# Rails 3: Form_tag + remote: true not working even with proper JS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a simple form for uploading a file:

```
    <%= form_tag(admin_file_uploads_path, remote: true, multipart: true) do %>
        <%= label_tag "Inventory Status" %>
        <%= file_field_tag :inventory_status %>
        <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
    <% end %>
```

And the source shows that `jquery`, `jquery-ujs`, and `jquery-ui` are all are included:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I want to process form submission with AJAX. It seems like all the pieces are in place, but it's still being processed as HTML. The log says `Processing by Admin::FileUploadsController#create as HTML`. What am I missing??

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that files actually exist at those three asset paths?

Comment: Yea, they all have responses when I check firebug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't upload files via AJAX, so apparently your request comes as plain HTML, coz you don't have anything specific to :js and rails thinks it's just a plain HTML POST request.

Comment: This isn't strictly true.  You *can* upload files via AJAX.  Just not with vanilla jquery and rails remote: true calls.  For instance... you can use this: https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails

Comment: yup, you're right, there are plenty of workarounds, i was trying to point him to the problem with uploads, that's all

Comment: nice to know. I'll just remove that feature. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload files via AJAX, but there are many gems that can helpful ,I'v used remotipart gem its really very nice and easy.

hope you will get your solution.

https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart